# In a ListBox with TextBoxes, how do I focus on the added TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a list box of text boxes and a button that adds a new item to the list box. When I click on the add button, I'd like the new item to be selected and the containing text box to have focus.

I can easily select the new item via binding, but I haven't figured out how to focus the text box. I couldn't do it from the view model because the new text box isn't created until later.

To show you the problem, I've created a sample Solution (available on GitHub: [TestListBoxWithTextBox](https://github.com/redcurry/TestListBoxWithTextBox)).

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="TestListBoxWithTextBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    >
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button
            Content="Add"
            Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Here are my view models (`ViewModelBase` comes from the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();

    private ItemViewModel selectedItem;
    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get => selectedItem;
        set => Set(nameof(SelectedItem), ref selectedItem, value);
    }

    public ICommand AddItemCommand =>
        new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            var newItem = new ItemViewModel();
            Items.Add(newItem);
            SelectedItem = newItem;
        });
}

public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => Set(nameof(Name), ref name, value);
    }
}
```

#### Things I've Tried

**Talk to the view from the view model:** I created an interface `IView` with the method `FocusTextBox(int index)`. The view implemented this interface and the view model called its method after selecting the new item (in `AddItemCommand`). However, the view wasn't able to find the `TextBox` because it didn't yet exist, even though I added the new item to the `Items` list.

**Focus the `TextBox` on its `Loaded` event:** The `Loaded` event guarantees that the `TextBox` exists, so it makes sense to try to get the focus there. This works in this simple example, but not in my actual program. In my program, when you enter something in the `TextBox` and then press the add button, the focus is moved away from the text box, which then calls a separate command to sort the items. During sorting, some text boxes are moved and this causes their `Loaded` event to be called, which then steal the focus from the add button, so it behaves as if the add button was never pressed.

**Focus the `TextBox` on the `ListBox.ItemContainingGenerator.StatusChanged` event:** When the selected item changes in the list box, I listen to the `ItemContainingGenerator.StatusChanged` event. This event is fired when the items in the list box are being generated or finished generating. When they're finished generating, I find the `TextBox` inside the selected item (set in the view model) and focus on it. This solution works, but not consistently. In some of my list boxes, this doesn't work and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

i have added a minor changes to your code .. and i think it work ...

try this:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox MinWidth="100" Text="{Binding Name}" Initialized="TextBoxElement_OnInitialized"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and in your code-behind:

```
 private int _textBoxCounter = 0;
        private void TextBoxElement_OnInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_textBoxCounter < MyListBox.Items.Count)
            {
                Keyboard.Focus((IInputElement)sender);
                _textBoxCounter++;
            }

        }
```

this way you Guarantee that the focus will not be set during sort operation

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in my actual program. As I mentioned, when something is typed in a text box and it loses focus (such as when the Add button is pressed), it may be moved to another position to satisfy a sort order. When this move happens, the moved text box's Initialized event is fired, causing it to gain focus, and therefore losing the focus of the Add button, so it behaves as it had never been pressed.

Comment: i have updated my answer ... please review it ... i thing that the mode=oneTime for the binding would do it ...

Comment: thank for your patience, i  have refreshed my answer ... it might help ... please let me now ..

Comment: It's still not working. The text box is reordered and a new one is shown, but the new one is not focused.

Comment: i think it would be much clearer if you supply the sort command